# Passing around array items in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How do I fix the below code so that the state of Group A gets updated and rendered correctly? On click people from Group A should move to Group B. My hunch is something with useEffect, but I can't think of a way to implement this as aCopy only exists within the click handler.

code:

````
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Test() {
  const [a, SetA] = useState(["Adam", "Brett", "Cody"]);
  const [b, SetB] = useState(["Donald", "Eric", "Fred"]);

  function click() {
    const aCopy = a;
    const mover = aCopy.pop();
    SetA(aCopy);
    SetB((prev) => [...prev, mover]);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>Group A: {a}</div>
      <div>Group B: {b}</div>
      <button onClick={click}>Click</button>
    </>
  );
}```
````

Comment: `const aCopy = a;` doesn't create a copy of the array

Comment: I think you need to do `const aCopy = [...a]`

Comment: `const aCopy = [...a]`; // This will create a copy

Comment: `const aCopy = [...a]` will create a *shallow copy* of the array; the elements of the array, if objects, will be references to the same objects. You're fine if you're using strings, as your code shows, but be forewarned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter the clicked item to remove it from one group while using the spread operator(`...`) to add it to the other group.

```
  const handleClickA = (item) => {
    SetA((prevA) => prevA.filter((o) => o !== item));
    SetB((prevB) => [...prevB, item]);
  };
```

This would work as you want. It can move items in between the groups as you expect.

`handleClickA` and `handleClickB` are almost same. You can reduce this to a single function if the information about the group is also available for each item.

```js
function Test() {
  const [a, SetA] = React.useState(["Adam", "Brett", "Cody"]);
  const [b, SetB] = React.useState(["Donald", "Eric", "Fred"]);

  const handleClickA = (item) => {
    SetA((prevA) => prevA.filter((o) => o !== item));
    SetB((prevB) => [...prevB, item]);
  };

  const handleClickB = (item) => {
    SetB((prevB) => prevB.filter((o) => o !== item));
    SetA((prevA) => [...prevA, item]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Group A:{" "}
        {a.map((itemA, indexA) => (
          <button key={indexA} onClick={() => handleClickA(itemA)}>
            {itemA}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        Group B:{" "}
        {b.map((itemB, indexB) => (
          <button key={indexB} onClick={() => handleClickB(itemB)}>
            {itemB}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```